# Images set in UItableView getting misplaced for different row when getting image from server and set

Tags: ios

We are using haneke for image cache , When setting images for UITable view it is making a call to server to get image and set to image view in row. But due to delay in server call to get image 1 row images is assigned to 2 nd row like that it is misplacing ,Can you please suggest better way to handle UItableViewCell in this scenario.

Code snippet for cell preparation:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
let contact = searchedResults[indexPath.row]
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ConversationContactCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ConversationContactCell
cell.contactImage.image = nil
ImageCache.getInstance()?.getUserImage(contact.contactImageURI, gender: contact.contactGender, imageRetrievalHandler: { (image) in
    cell.contactImage.image = image
})
cell.contactName.text = contact.contactName
return cell
```

}

Comment: can you show ur tried code

Comment: please post your code for your cell creation, and the cell itself.

Comment: Code snippet for cell preparation:

Comment: Any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your images are getting reused when the cells are dequeued, then updated when the cell's images are finished downloading from the internet.

You should clear the image in your ConversationContactCell class like so:

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()
    contactImage.image = nil        
}
```

This will clear the images each time the cell is reused. Let me know if that helps!